# Western Digital NAS User File Locations

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, nas

I took the hard drive out of a Wetern Digital NAS and plugged it into my linux machine and mounted it, but I can't figure out where the user files are stored.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "user files"? The files you put on it while you were using it as a NAS? Or some kind of configuration files?

Comment: What DO you see?  Anything?  Have you tried a basic file system search for known file names?

Comment: I see the basic linux file structure...  it's an OS...  but there's nothing of interest in the /home dir of the drive....

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to check the following directories for anything resembeling the hard drives ID/Name:

```
/dev
/media
/mnt
```